# Universal graphs on higher cardinals

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, model-theory

The Rado graph contains every finite graph as induced subgraph, and its also holds for countable graphs. So it is an universal graph of size $\aleph_0$, which contains all graphs of size $\aleph_0$ as induced subgraph.

**Question:** Is it also true for higher cardinals? Does there exist a graph of size $\kappa$, which contains all graphs of size $\kappa$ as induced subgraph? If not, what is the condition for $\kappa$?

Comment: I think that you probably need some assumptions about cardinal arithmetics. Something like $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on Asaf's comment, indeed, if  $\kappa^{\lt\kappa}=\kappa$, then we may build a $\kappa$-universal graph of size $\kappa$. Proceed in $\kappa$ many stages. At each stage, we have a graph of size $\gamma$, less than $\kappa$. There are precisely $2^\gamma\leq\kappa$ many ways to add a single new point to this graph. Using a pairing function, we add at stage $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$ a point realizing the $\beta^{th}$ pattern of connectivity with the points constructed at stage $\alpha$. It follows that after $\kappa$ many stages, we will have a $\kappa$-universal graph, since for any graph of size $\kappa$, we enumerate its nodes and then systematically find a copy inside our universal graph realizing that pattern of connectivity with the previous nodes. This is the "forth" part of the usual back-and-forth arguments.

Comment: Is this condition necessary? Could one construct a counterexample by assuming the negation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will: It's not a necessary condition, I found this now: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007284900423.

Answer (score 9):

An old result of Shelah states that if one adds $\lambda > \kappa^{++}$ Cohen subsets to a cardinal satisfying $\kappa^{<\kappa}$, then in the resulting universe the universality number for graphs on $\kappa^+$ is $\lambda$. It is possible to have a universal graph of size $\aleph_1$ even when CH fails (Mekler and Shelah independently).

Comment: Mirna: Welcome!

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!